# Kendo MVC date filter customization

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-mvc

I have a MVC kendo grid date head filter

```
part of my date column filter--
.Filterable(filterable => filterable.Extra(true).UI("customDateFilter")
.Operators(operators => operators
.ForDate(date => date.Clear()
.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Is greater than or equal to")
.IsLessThanOrEqualTo("Is less than or equal to")
.IsEqualTo("Is equal to");
```

```
and my js custom function--
function customDateFilter(element) {
    element.kendoDatePicker({
        format: "MM/yyyy",
        dateInput: true,
        start: "year",
        parseFormats: ["MM/yyyy"],
        depth: "year",
        min: new Date(2000, 01, 01)
    });
}
```

I'm currently using MM/yyyy format in my grid, so the search date option should also be MM/yyyy. However, because of this, if I search "greater than OR equal to 09/2020",

it omits 09/2020 and returns 10/2020 and so on. I noticed that if I change the search date format to MM/dd/yyyy and select 09/01/2020 then "greater than OR equal to 09/2020" includes 09/2020.

Is there a way IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo and IsLessThanOrEqualTo to work with using the format MM/yyyy?